# How to keep element ratio without JavaScript

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to adapt the dimensions of some items on my HTML page to the size of the window. I know it can be done quite easily with JQuery with something like :

```
 $(window).resize(function(){
     var width = $(this).width();
     $(item).css('height',(height * w / h)+ 'px'); // w and h are variables used to calculate the ratio
 });
```

However I am looking for a way to do it with CSS.
I have an centered item that occupies 40% of the width of the window. So when the width of the window is reduced, the width of the item is reduced too, but the height is the same. So all I want is the ratio to be the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height to 0, and then add a padding-bottom: X% where X is the image's aspect ratio.  You can get the ratio with SASS by using

```
.element{ padding-bottom: percentage(height/width); }
```

Also, this can be used in conjunction with a background image and using background-size:cover; to make the image responsive.